# Concatenate nvarchar and int while maintaining Distinct result

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to count all the items for each brand and concatenate the brand name + number of items.

I have this query in SQL Server 2008 R2:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    Brands.BrandName + ' ' + COUNT(Items.ITEMNO) as ITEMSNO,
    Brands.BrandId
FROM Items, Brand_Products, Brands
WHERE    
    Items.ITEMNO=Brand_Products.ItemNo
    AND Brands.BrandId=Brand_Products.BrandId
    AND Items.SubcategoryID='SCat-020'
GROUP BY 
    Brands.BrandId,
    Brands.BrandName,
    Items.ITEMNO
```

I'm trying to concatenate 2 fields, but I have 2 problems:

1. if I do this as shown in my example here I have a problem with `nvarchar` and `int`.
2. if I use convert I have a problem with (Distinct)

Any help? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work, fist you count items based on BrandId in CTE and than join it with Brand table.

```
WITH    ItemCount
      AS ( SELECT BrandId
               ,COUNT(Items.ITEMNO) AS item_Count
            FROM Items
               ,Brand_Products
               ,Brands
            WHERE Items.ITEMNO = Brand_Products.ItemNo
                AND Brands.BrandId = Brand_Products.BrandId
                AND Items.SubcategoryID = 'SCat-020'
            GROUP BY Brands.BrandId)
SELECT b.BrandName + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), Item_Count)
    FROM Brands AS b
    JOIN ItemCount AS I
        ON b.BrandId = i.BrandId
```

Comment: just a question, is it possible to select BrandId field and the concatenated string?

Comment: yes, just alter the `select b.brandid, b.BrandName + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), Item_Count)`

Answer (score 1):

Retrieve the field you're looking for twice, once in the concatenated field answer, and once by itself.  This should solve your issue with DISTINCT.

Answer (score 0):

Convert to `varchar` before concatenating

```
'Whatever ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), COUNT(Items.ITEMNO)) + ' Whatever '
```

Comment: NEVER use `varchar` without a length parameter.  It is dangerous, because the default is different in different contexts.

Comment: thanks for your fast answer, it works fine, but distinct always gives me 1 instead of 5 for each brand.
I can't remove distinct because it will repeat the brand name for each item!!