# Display other fields with concatenated fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21143335/concatenate-nvarchar-and-int-while-maintaining-distinct-result) I got this result:

```
    WITH    ItemCount
      AS ( SELECT BrandId
               ,COUNT(Items.ITEMNO) AS item_Count
            FROM Items
               ,Brand_Products
               ,Brands
            WHERE Items.ITEMNO = Brand_Products.ItemNo
                AND Brands.BrandId = Brand_Products.BrandId
                AND Items.SubcategoryID = 'SCat-020'
            GROUP BY Brands.BrandId)
SELECT b.BrandName + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), Item_Count)
    FROM Brands AS b
    JOIN ItemCount AS I
        ON b.BrandId = i.BrandId
```

what i want to add is to select the concatenated string and BrandId as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless this is some kind of trick question, you'd just add it to the `SELECT` list:

```
SELECT b.BrandId, b.BrandName + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), Item_Count)
    FROM Brands AS b
    JOIN ItemCount AS I
        ON b.BrandId = i.BrandId
```

Comment: @Samira, I'm glad I could be of assistance!